# IN.UI.Share() success callback not working

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'd like to use Linkedin share functionality with my custom button, but the callback function won't be called on success, any idea?

This is my code:

```
var sh = IN.UI.Share().params(
{
    url: "someUrl"
});
sh.success(function(){console.log('Linkedin share success')});
sh.place();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a mini-pen which you can view here https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/Bqqbjz

Documentation on this subject can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

```js
IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', function() {
    var shareLink = document.getElementById('shareLink');
    shareLink.onclick = function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var params = {
        "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! https://www.example.com",
        "visibility": {
          "code": "anyone"
        }
      };

      IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(params))
      .result(function(xhrResult){
        alert('success :)');
      })
      .error(function(errorObj){
        alert('Error');
        alert(errorObj.errorMessage);
      });
    };

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering a 4 years old question, I don't even remember the project :D

Comment: Only a pleasure, encountered a similar issue with LinkedIn apis this week so thought I would share the findings